# Failed to implement the update data functionality in my chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build an extension which clubs tabs together into a group and when url of the clubbed  tabs gets changed it gets updated so that next time you click on group name of that particular group you get updated changes.
But since it's my first time building a chrome extension I have failed to implement this functionality. Help me complete this part of my project. ;)

```
 let allGroupNames = [];
let storedGroupsData = {}
const urlHistoryMap = new Map();
```

**This functions fetch all the opened tabs in the window**

```
// url and tabID of the opened tabs
const fetchOpenedTabs = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await chrome.tabs.query({});
        const data = await response;
        data.map((item) => {
            urlHistoryMap.set(item.id, item.url)
            
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

**fetches the groups data stored in the chrome local storage**

```
const fetchStoredData = async () => {
    try {
        storedGroupsData = (await chrome.storage.local.get('storedGroupsData')).storedGroupsData || {};
        allGroupNames = Object.keys(storedGroupsData);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

**load both the things when user opens the chrome for the first time**

```
 fetchStoredData();
    fetchOpenedTabs();
```

**check whether the URL in which change happened is the URL that you want to sync **

*How I am trying to achieved this is that, fetchOpenedtabs() fetches all the opened tabs and store it  as a Map of tabID and it's associated URL. When a change happens it check whether a change take place in the tab whose url I want to sync or not.*

```
 chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
        if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
            console.log('urlHistoryMap', urlHistoryMap);
            // url in which the change happened 
            const oldUrl = urlHistoryMap.get(tabId);
            const newUrl = tab.url;
            const newTitle = tab.title;

            allGroupNames.map((groupName) => {
                storedGroupsData[groupName].forEach((tabProp, index) => {
```

**this condition checks if the URL that changed is stored in my database or not.**

```
 if (oldUrl == tabProp.url) {
                        console.log("old Url in if statement", oldUrl);
                        const tabData = {
                            groupName: `${groupName}`,
                            // title of the new url 
                            title: `${newTitle}`,
                            // new url
                            url: `${newUrl}`,
                            muted: false
                        };
                        storedGroupsData[groupName][index] = tabData;
                        chrome.storage.local.set({ 'storedGroupsData': storedGroupsData }).then(
                            () => {
                                // console.log('storedData', storedGroupsData)
                            })
                    }
                })
            })
            urlHistoryMap.set(tabId, newUrl);
        }
        return
    });
```